# Handle downgrade strategy with stripe

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

i'm building an app with multiple subscriptions plan for my users.

Let's say my user as a 'free' plan, and want to upgrade to a 'pro' plan.I'm using stripe customer billing portal, which work perfectly.

But when i want to downgrade, i would like the plan to change only a the subscription period end, unfortunately, it's change immediatly.

I know i can handle it from API, but i need to do it from the customer portal generated by stripe.
Any idea how to configure my stripe customer portal to handle downgrade this way ?

Answer (score 1):

> i would like the plan to change only a the subscription period end, unfortunately, it's change immediately.

This is not *completely* supported with Subscriptions and the Customer Portal. Any change you make to the Subscription's SubscriptionItems is immediate, e.g. changing from price_123 to price_678 happens the moment you update the Subscription.

However, using the [`proration_behavior: 'none'` parameter on a CustomerPortal Configuration](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create?lang=node#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-proration_behavior), you can configure it to not create prorations or invoice the Customer immediately but instead, defer the new payment amount on to the next Invoice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, it would be a nice solution if i didn't needed to wait before update the plan, just delaying the payment. Sadly, it didn't fit the behaviour when user downgrade plan. I want them to keep them same plan until the end of current subscription.